Axler Example 3.100 on quotient spaces
In Axler's linear algebra textbook, he gives an example of a quotient space as $\mathbb{R}^3/U$, where $U$ is a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ containing the origin. The quotient, he claims, is the set of lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ parallel to $U$.
I am trying to understand exactly what this means and how to graph it. I tried to use his example of $\mathbb{R}^2/U$ where $U$ is a line through $\mathbb{R}^2$. If, say, $U = \{(x,2x)\}$, this is the set of lines parallel to the line $y = 2x$, so all lines with slope $2$ (just varying the $y$-intercept). I tried to envision "embedding this space in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by considering, say, the line $U = \{(x,2x,0)\}$. The calculation should be essentially the exact same, and the equivalence classes are the set of lines with slope $2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ projected down to the $x-y$ plane. I'm having trouble reconciling this with the definition of a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is the set
$$
\left\{(x,y,z) = (a_1, a_2, a_3) + t (v_1, v_2, v_3) \mid t \in \mathbb{R} \right\}.
$$
If this were in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the fact that it contains the origin would imply that the intercept has to be $0$, but I think I determined with some toy examples that this isn't the case in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

ummm. Given your line $t(1,2,0),$   you're better off  considering the orthogonal plane through the origin $W: ; x+2y = 0.$  Any parallel line $(x_0, y_0, z_0) +t(1,2,0))$  intersects the plane $W$  in a single point.

in the third edition this is 3.84 page 95.

Quotient spaces can be thought of as a projection as well. So for each point in the plane  perpendicular to $U$ there is exactly one line parallel to $U$ that crosses it. Those lines are the cosets of the quotient space.

OP, can you clarify the actual question you're asking? I understand the context and feel like I'm close to being able to help, but I can't actually tell what specific thing you want help with.
